# How to access the element using "this"

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I need to access a SPAN tag with in every DIV tag 
so i used this following code

```
    $("DIV").click(function(){      
    $(this + "SPAN").show();
});
```

Is the above code is correct? Its not working for me! Its showing nothing too.. 

Please help me

Thanks,
Praveen J

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for getting an element inside another, like this:

```
$("div").click(function(){      
  $(this).find("span").show();
});
```

As a general rule, to get anything relative to `this`, you're typically going to start with `$(this)` and some combination of the [tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to move around.

---

*For actual code, based on comments below:*
If your code looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Link</legend>
  <span>CHECK</span>
</fieldset>
```

Then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) won't work since on `$("legend")` selector because the `<span>` isn't *inside* the `<legend>` it's a sibling, so use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (optionally with a selector) like this:

```
$("legend").click(function(){ 
  $(this).siblings("span").show(); 
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2Bxem/1/)

Comment: Using `this` as a "context" is an alternative: `$("div").click(function(){ $("span", this).show(); });`

Comment: @digitala - It's converted to the same `.find()` call :) Just many more steps to get there, including 2 regexes :) ....you can take a look at the source here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L153

Comment: the source is like this! <fieldset><legend>Link</legend><span>CHECK</span></fieldset>
The solution is good, but its not working here..

Comment: @praveenjayapal - I don't see a `<div>` in there...can you post everything relevant?

Comment: Here the exact code,
<fieldset><legend>Link</legend><span>CHECK</span></fieldset>

$("legend").click(function(){
$(this).find("span").show();
});

Intially the span is hidden

Comment: @praveenjayapal - Ah, you need `.siblings()` rather than `.find()`, since it's not *in* the element, like this: `$("legend").click(function(){ $(this).siblings("span").show(); });​` [you can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2Bxem/)

Comment: yes, thanks Nick.. working good.. and also thanks for showing me a good stuff jsFiddle.. really nice..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the find function to do that. (Also, using lowercase for selectors is preferred.)

```
$("div").click(function(){      
    $(this).find("span").show();
});
```